# Flask SocketIo : test emission of event

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, emit

I am building an application that is used Flask SocketIO. To understand exactly how work the StocketIO Package, I have create a simple test with this workflow :

1. HTTP Get request to trigger my even
2. when I receive this Request, I emit event with SocketIO with the function test()
3. I try to read this event emit with the function handle_my_custom_event().

Here is my code :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
socket = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    data = {'city': "new york", 'number': 10}
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    socket.emit("test_event", json_data)
    return {"message": "message send correctly"}, 200


@socket.on('test_event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    print('received json: ' + str(json))
    return 'one', 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket.run(app)
```

I execute my HTTP request to my localhost : http://127.0.0.1:5000/
That trigger my function test which emit my event (in the terminal I have the message "emitting event "test_event" to all [/]" so the event is emit)

and normally, my handle_my_custom_event should be trigger by this event because it listent "test_event", but nothing happen and nothing is printed in the terminal (I don't have the "received json: xx")

So I suppose that this event is not listen on the good way, but in that case if you have an idea why, it would really help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how Socket.IO works. When you call `emit()` in the server, you are emitting to your clients. The event handler for this `test_event` event that you emitted should be implemented in your client.

When the client does an emit, then it would be the server receiving it, so in that case you would be implementing an event handler in the server.